# I can't change textblock's value after 'StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames'

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames sAnimation = new StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    int full = 100;
    double key = 4000 / full;

    for (var i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        TimeSpan keyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((100 - i) * key);
        DiscreteStringKeyFrame frame = new DiscreteStringKeyFrame(i.ToString(), KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(keyTime));
        sAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(frame);
    }

    Storyboard.SetTarget(sAnimation, textCount);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(sAnimation, new PropertyPath(TextBlock.TextProperty));

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

    sb.Children.Add(sAnimation);
    sb.Completed += sb_Completed;
    sb.Begin(this);
}

private void sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textCount.Text = "50";
}
```

this is my code.

this code is change textblock's value 100 to 0.

And I want to change textblock's value after count down is finished.

But it doesn't change even though count down (animating) is finished.
(I try to change textblock's value when storyboard is completed)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add one line in your above code :

```
sAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
```

This way the animation will stop effecting your target controls after the storyboard has completed.

Comment: I am sorry that i assumed that you want to change the text after the animation anyway. You can do one more thing if you want the text to remain after animation. You can put this line in the completed event of your storyboard :-      textCount.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.TextProperty, null);